# Angular 4 - Change Background color of Stepper depending on the status

Tags: angular

I am creating a stepper in angular 4. I am not using angular material stepper. I need to change the background color of the stepper depending upon the status that I will receive from API. For example: If the status is "publish", the background color of the first stepper should be orange and if the status is "publishing" then the color of the first stepper should be green and the background color of the second stepper should be orange.
 It would be great if anyone can help on this.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation"  *ngFor=" let stepper of stepperBtns">
                  <div>
                    <button  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getstatusBtnColor()}" [type]="stepper.type" class="round-tab">{{stepper.name}}</button>
                  </div> 
                  
                </li>
              </ul>
```

```js
getstatusBtnColor(){
   if (status== 'publish'){
        return 'orange';
      }
      else if (status == 'publishing'){
      return 'green';
      }
      }
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slhwpu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: shouldn't you pass a parameter in getstatusBtnColor() ?? getstatusBtnColor(stepper.status)... inside the TS file, you handle the passed status... getstatusBtnColor(passedStatus){
   if (passedStatus== 'publish'){
        return 'orange';
      }
      else if (passedStatus == 'publishing'){
      return 'green';
      }
      }

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML looks correct to me. However your Typescript function is a little off - you're not getting the value of `status` from anywhere that I can see.

Try something like:

```
getstatusBtnColor(status: string) {
  switch(status) {
    case 'publish':
      return 'orange';
    case 'publishing':
      return 'green';

    default:
      return 'red';
  }
}
```

Then pass your status into the function from the HTML.
(I added the default case to help in case the issue is your status not having the correct value)

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9uuaaj

Comment: Hi @8ytan, Thanks you for your reply. But Switch case will not work in my case as the status will be more than one and the status is in separate object. I have tried using a loop and bind the status but it is not working. Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9uuaaj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @ShradhaMallick Could you provide me with more info about what you're trying to do? The StackBlitz you linked just goes to my original example...

Comment: Hi @8ytan. please check this url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slhwpu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. I want to change the background color of the buttons based on the status.

Comment: @Shraddh Okay, I see your issue. You seem to be trying to change the colour of the status buttons up top according to the data in the table - what are you trying to achieve? Sorry to keep asking for more info but could you send me a picture of what you want it to look like when it's done?

Answer (score 0):

use the style attributes `[style.background-color]` instead of `ngStyle`

`<button [style.background-color]="getstatusBtnColor()" [type]="stepper.type" class="round-tab">{{stepper.name}}</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML section is right. Please check **getstatusBtnColor** typescript method. You are not providing last else condition,  in-case both top conditions fail. Are your sure **status** field do have one of these two possible values?? May be try with this

```
getstatusBtnColor(){
   if (status== 'publish'){
    return 'orange';
  }
  else if (status == 'publishing'){
  return 'green';
  }else{
   return 'blue';  //just to check 'status' value, in case status is neither publish nor publishing
  }
  }
```